# Nested selector in Jquery next

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following HTML

```
<div id="header1" class="toggle">Section 1 : Create an account</div>
<div id="section1">
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</div>
```

I want to disable all `input` elements which are in a `div` which is next to `div` with `class="toggle"`.
In above exmple `div` with `id="header1"` have `class="toggle"`,I want to disable all `input`elements  which are in `div` next to it i.e. input elements within `div` with `id="section1"`.

I tried  `$('.toggle').next(div input)).attr("disabled", true);` but no luck. I am not sure if we can use nested selector in `next()`.

Comment: can you do jsfiddle with your attempts please? then it will be easy to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use next and then find:

```
$('.toggle').next('div').find('input').attr("disabled", true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b8n2k/1/

Or using an expanded version of 3nigmas answer:

```
$('div.toggle+div input').attr("disabled", true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b8n2k/

Answer (score 2):

See **[Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/)**

```
$("div.toggle+div").find(":input").prop("disabled",true);
```

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of selector("prev + next").